# Как можно получить подключено ли устройство к bluetooth без использования CBManager?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-le

Я заметил, что при подключении к bluetooth в машине 2gis сразу выдает маршрут.
Тестировал использовать машину без bluetooth, фича не работает.
Я хотел повторить этот трюк или хотя бы понять как он работает, но не нашел нужной инфы. Перепробовал получения с CBPeripheral, но он не выдает такой информации, или я что-то делал не так. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону смотреть.

Comment: Что значит "сразу выдаёт маршрут"? Подключаете по CarPlay, или просто к звуковой системе?

Comment: К звуковой системе машины по bluetooth. После подключения приходит пуш от 2gis.